Title: Parallelizing Google Speech-to-Text Transcription of Multiple GCS URIs in Python
Explanation:
I'm working on a project where I need to transcribe multiple audio files stored in Google Cloud Storage (GCS) to text using Google Speech-to-Text API in Python. I have a list of GCS URIs, and I want to process them in parallel to save time. However, my current implementation using ThreadPoolExecutor doesn't seem to be efficient. I'm wondering if there's a better way to achieve parallel processing for transcribing these audio files.
Background Research:
I've tried using ThreadPoolExecutor for parallel processing, but it doesn't seem to be as efficient as I hoped. I'm aware that Google Speech-to-Text API supports asynchronous batch processing, but I'm unsure how to implement it for multiple GCS URIs in Python.
Question:
Is there a more efficient way to parallelize the transcription of multiple audio files stored in Google Cloud Storage to text using Google Speech-to-Text API in Python, specifically when dealing with a list of GCS URIs?

the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example
